# Clipboard paste error

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, vnc-viewer

In Microsoft Excel, when using mouse to move or copy a cell I get an error message box after 2 seconds stating:

```
There's a problem with the clipboard, but you can still paste your content within this workbook.
```

[image: Excel paste error msg box]

Despite the error, the pasted data ends up as expected. How can I avoid the delay and suppress the error message?

Only happens if the pasting is due to a mouse move & release left-button event. Works fine if I paste using ctrl+v. Also only happens if I am running a VNC viewer at the same time.

Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit

Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO 64-bit

TigerVNC Viewer 32-bit v1.9.0

Comment: Try: (1) In *Options > General*, under User Interface Options, to uncheck Enable Live Preview. (2) If you have installed any clipboard manager, uninstall it.

Comment: @harrymc tried disabling "Enable Live Preview" but no luck. I do not have any clipboard manager except what is done by the VNC Viewer.

Comment: @DavidPostill I disagree with your change of my title. Titles should contain the text people will google, and not the most descriptive sentence. That is how I use these fora, and the reason it had the full error message verbatim.

Comment: No it didn't. You cannot have the word "problem" in the title. Titles are meant to describe the issue not contain error messages (which belong in the question body).

Answer (score 1):

When Excel shows this dialog after a copy (CTRL+C) action, it means that another app has a lock on the system clipboard. In this situation, users can still paste within Excel.  However users cannot paste to another app like Word or Outlook which uses the clipboard.

Reference links:

**Similar discussion:**
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_365hp/theres-a-problem-with-the-clipboard-but-you-can/6720299f-1084-4104-93cc-abee9dcf7469

**Feature request in User Voice of Excel:**
https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/18508126-remove-the-pointless-message-there-s-a-problem-wi

Comment: yes, probably the correct explanation. However I am looking for a fix.